# GET запрос через C++

Tags: c++, get

Я уже невероятно долго пытаюсь сделать GET запрос, но ничего не получается, и меня это уже сильно занадоело, поэтому вопрос из серии "сделайте за меня"

Сам проект - Twitch bot. Сейчас мне нужно подключаться к `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/`
Инструкция от твича - https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/ingests

Пример того, что я хочу получить -

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/qwerty?client_id=2z3hmhg99d9lga6s3gqme5mwbhrqbx

Уже пробовал подключаться через сокет, подключал `<boost/asio.hpp>`, но всё ещё в упор не понимаю, что значит

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/ingests'
```

и что мне с ним делать.

Разбирал код других ботов, которые выложены на гитхабе, в одном из них использовалось

```
    const auto curl = curl_easy_init();
    auto url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channel_id;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &Callback);
#ifdef VERBOSE
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
#endif

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    try {
        auto parsed = nlohmann::json::parse(write_data);
        write_data.clear();
        if (!parsed.is_object()) {  // Invalid response: not an object
            return { };
        }
#if 0
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> json_values;
        std::vector<std::string> json_names = {"url",    "game",      "logo",
            "views",  "followers", "partner",
            "mature", "updated_at"};
        for (const auto element : json_names) {
            const auto object = parsed.find(element);
            if (object != parsed.end()) {
                if (object->is_string()) {
                    json_values.push_back(
                        make_tuple(element, object->get<std::string>()));
                } else if (object->is_number()) {
                    json_values.push_back(
                        make_tuple(element, std::to_string(object->get<int32_t>())));
                }
            }
        }
#endif
```

Пытался использовать curl, но компилятор постоянно ругается на неразрешенный символ.

Короче - надоело.

Подскажите, как на плюсах выполнить эту задачу, или дайте ресурс, из которого можно просто скопипастить, и что бы всё работало. Ибо мне уже надоело пытаться решить задачу, которая состоит из 2х строк в JS`е.

UPDATE

```
    #include "curl\curl.h"
    #pragma comment(lib,"libcurl_a.lib")

    int main() {
        CURL *curl;

        curl = curl_easy_init();
    }
```

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_curl_easy_init в функции main

Так же есть Предупреждение  LNK4272 тип компьютера библиотеки "X86" конфликтует с типом целевого компьютера "x64"
Но даже если я ставлю запуск в 86, то пропадает только предупреждение, ошибка остаётся

Comment: а [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) то с библиотеками установлен?

Comment: @Fat-Zer ага. Как и было в инструкции: вытащить libcurl_a.lib из curl-7.58.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib и написать #pragma comment(lib,"libcurl_a.lib")

Comment: @Виталий А хидеры curl в инклудах прописаны?

Comment: @Виталий >> `но компилятор постоянно ругается на неразрешенный символ` — компилятор или линкер? и ошибку в студию... ставлю на то, что либо сам curl не подключил в проект, либо его зависимости...

Comment: @Fat-Zer дополнил

Comment: @Виталий, посмотри, как в MSVS подключать статические библиотеки для линковки... скорей всего libcurl_a.lib забыл прописать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer задницу почти разорвал, но смог заставить курл работать. Можно сказать, что проблема решена. Напиши ответ, что бы плюсик поставил

Comment: @Виталий, лучше сам опиши, что именно сделал и на какие грабли наступал... может кому-то в будущем пригодиться...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Итак, что я сделал и на сколько костылей наступил:

Мне нужно было: использовать библию `curl`, при этом не привязывая проект к локальной папке на компе, т.е. что бы можно было открыть проект на любом компе.

Пропущу все мои фейлы, и сразу к сути:

1. делаем всё то, что делает этот челик - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su74zabqP94
2. создаём свой проект обычным способом
3. папку `curl`, а так же файлы `libcurld.lib` и `libcurld.dll`, которые мы получили, повторив действия того челика, копируем туда, где наши файлы проекта
4. в нужный нам файл пишем `#include "curl/curl.h"` `#pragma comment(lib, "libcurld.lib")`
5. ???
6. Proфит!

Да, жопокриво, задоруко, но работает (по крайней у меня). При этом другие инструкции у меня не работали.

Ссылка на бота из моего примера - https://github.com/PhraseMan/Twitch-Library
только нужно немного подправить все ссылки, теперь нужно дописывать client_id, но можно воспользоваться ид, который я у кого-то любезно стырил 2z3hmhg99d9lga6s3gqme5mwbhrqbx, т.е. итоговая ссылка `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ТВОЙ_ЧЕНЕЛ?client_id=2z3hmhg99d9lga6s3gqme5mwbhrqbx`

Может можно было всё сделать проще, но я в этом разбираться не собираюсь, и эта инструкция от ламера ламерам.